# How to create an empty file of the specified size in Windows by C++ or C or C#?

Tags: c#, c++, c, windows

How to create an empty file of the specified size in Windows by C++ or C or C# ?

This file does not take up disk space, Open the file, there isn't anything. **But file has number of bytes in the file properties.**

```
For example--
```

[image]

Comment: Doesn't contain anything but still claims to have a size... sounds like "sparse file". I've never messed with that myself, but you can google it and try what you find. Good luck.

Comment: What do you mean by "open the file, there isn't anything" ?  The number of bytes shown in the file properties is the number of bytes you find if you open the file ... unless the file has one or more alternate streams, of course.  Are you talking about files with alternate streams?

Comment: You could simply seek to the desired EOF position with SetFilePointer() and call SetEndOfFile().  That creates the file on an NTFS file system with the desired size but no allocated clusters.  Reading such a file produces binary zeros.

Comment: @HansPassant: I'm fairly sure the space will be allocated, unless you've explicitly made the file sparse.  It won't be zeroed out preemptively, but it *will* be allocated.  (This behaviour might be affected by compression, I guess, if you've got it turned on.)

Comment: Well, I'm 100% sure it doesn't.  Easy to test, create a 100 gigabyte file that way.  Takes a fraction of a second.

Comment: @Hans: yes, it happens quickly because the clusters are just allocated, not zeroed.  That's just a matter of updating the bitmap file and writing the data runs into the MFT.  But I've just checked using the Sysinternals Diskview tool and the clusters really *are* being allocated to the file.  (You can also see the amount of free space on the volume change.)

Answer (score 1):

You can do in c++ like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<char> empty(1024, 0);
    std::ofstream ofs("ouput.img", std::ios::binary | std::ios::out);

    for(int i = 0; i < 1024*300; i++)
    {
        if (!ofs.write(&empty[0], empty.size()))
        {
            std::cerr << "problem writing to file" << std::endl;
            return 255;
        }
    }
}
```

In c#: to make 2GB of file:
Simply create the file, seek to a suitably large offset, and write a single byte:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"c:\tmp\huge_dummy_file", FileMode.CreateNew);
fs.Seek(2048L * 1024 * 1024, SeekOrigin.Begin);
fs.WriteByte(0);
fs.Close();
```

Comment: Such a file doesn't meet the OPs specifications, e.g., it takes up disk space.